# How far can I scroll?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple script that scrolls to the bottom.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    window.scroll.after(i * 5, [0, i]);
```

The above script works perfectly, other then it doesn't scroll all the way, because it's only told to scroll 100 pixels down.

How can I tell how far down you can scroll? Or can I not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the document height and use that as the "bottom" value: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/

Answer (score 1):

You can just scroll to some ridiculously large value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4294967296; i++)
    window.scroll.after(i * 5, [0, i]);
```

I'm not sure what browser or library you're using that supports `scroll.after()` like that, though.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.scroll

Comment: [Ally](http://github.com/tylermwashburn/Ally). I like this answer, just for being adventurous. xD And I'm pretty sure you've answered a lot of my questions.

Comment: Man, something on that page absolutely wrecks my CPU when scrolling. Also, the GitHub link in [this post](http://allyframework.tumblr.com/post/3558661585) is broken. `:'(`

Comment: I switched repositories, and I lost that branch. :( Just use the latest 1.4 build. More compatibility, more stable, more features, better features, etc. It's nearing completion, so it's getting pretty stable right about now.